# Git and SVN, parallel

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Now we are going to migrate from SVN to Git, so I'm looking forward to use them in parallel for some time, so I need an ability to **every** developer to do `git svn dcommit`
What have l done:

1. Create central Git repo in GitLab
2. Clone central repo to local repo (lets call it `local1`)
3. `git svn init` + `git svn fetch` - to import SVN commits
4. Push from local repo to central
5. Clone central repo, to local repo (lets call it `local2`)

So the problem is that in `local1` I can do `git svn dcommit` and `git svn rebase` **but not in `local2`** (getting error `Unable to determine upstreaam SVN information from working tree history`).
As I see the problem is - there are no SVN configuration in `local2`, and also no `.rev_map`.

If I do just `git svn init` on `local2` - it doesnot help.

So I need to make SVN information "centralized" for every local Git repo, so every developer can do 
`git svn dcommit` + `rebase`, but how?

Comment: Why would you want to run in parallel? make the break.

Comment: For ex. we have some outsourcing, and it is the point to avoid full access to projects code, and it solved via SVN access management (sub folder access is granted) and for now I have no strategy to solve it in git. Also some training should be prepared and done.